# Battlefield 3 Network Problems (Lag)

Tags: battlefield-3, origin, networking

So a few weeks ago, I was playing BF3 as usual when everything suddenly stopped moving, everything froze and the game was shut down.  I also got a blank error message on Battlelog which did not help anything. I thought it was strange, but did not think much of it and instead went on to a different server, however, I noticed that when I flew jets (among other things), it felt like I hit something every five seconds, making it difficult to aim straight. Also the knife animation lags a lot. I have tried different servers, but it's the same everywhere even though I have a ping of around 60 ms.

Yesterday I decided to install BFBC2 again as I miss the feeling of the game in BF3, I saw that the I had same problem there, even BF 1942 when I tested it. I figured that it probably was something wrong with Origin, since I can play other online games without problems. So I re-installed Origin and removed all folders related with it and then installed it again, but without success.

Have also contacted EA support where they could not do much to help me.

Here is a small list of what I have tried:

- Re-installed Origin.
- Re-installed BF3.
- Re-installed Battlelog plugin.
- Opened all ports for BF3 in the router.
- Tried to change the "Network smoothing factor" in BF3.
- Installed the latest network and video drivers.
- Re-started the router.
- Tested other games (which is not on Origin) which seems to work really well.
- Tested BF3 single player, which works without problems, this should also rule out a problem with my hardware.

Here is also a short video of when it lags:

Does anyone have similar problems or a solution?

Comment: Have you tried playing offline? I don't think your knife animation problem is related to multiplayer.

Comment: Yes I have, and that works just fine, tho I don't remember if I tried knifing someone there... Will try it again later when I get home.

Comment: Hmm...the fact it does it in other games makes me think it's a graphics card issue, it's not overheating at all is it? Does it work okay with non-origin games? And are you on the latest drivers for your card?

Comment: This is only happening in origin games, other games that I install outside of Origin work just fine. I currently have a Gigabyte HD 6850 and it's never overheating, in games it's always around 50 C

Comment: Is it me or is there no (noticeable) lag in that video?

Comment: what is your ping in the servers? I know I had FPS drops problems with bf3 because of my RAM (which was capping when I had only 4 GB and made the FPS suddenly drop from to 4-5 then went up again). I had no trouble in the campaign though (multiplayer is harder on your PC than the campaign I guess, managing a big map with 64 players compared to the linear maps of the campaign)

Comment: @Alenanno I see what he's talking about. Not sure if it's lag or not, but I definitly see what he is describing about 'hitting something' in the jet every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: @Hugo Trudel I ussaly have around 60 ms, and at 60 fps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure its your internet. Since everyting works fine in singleplayer. Battlefield 3 needs to transfer a lot data during multiplayer and if you router cant handle it (or you have a bad connection or your provider doesn't allow you to use a lot internet traffic).
Try another internet provider, try to make the connection better or use another router. You could also contact your provider.

Sources:
Me while playing bf3 on xbox with bad connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ping by pressing tab in game.  Ping is the time (in milliseconds) that it takes for Battlefield to check with the server, and the server to respond (sort of like sonar, hence the name ping).  If your ping is over around 200, then the problem is simply your internet.  Some things that you can do to try and fix this are:

1. If you are connected through Wi-Fi, try getting closer to your modem, or better yet use an Ethernet cable.
2. If you are on PC, make sure that the server that you are connecting to is close.  If you are in California it will be much faster trying to communicate with a server in Dallas than one in Australia.
3. If all else fails, you just need to find a better internet provider.  Check http://www.speedtest.net/ to make sure that your internet connection is fast enough - 1 Mbit/s or higher is ideal.